# PrestaShop Installation on Windows - Unable to generate private keys using OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, windows-10, prestashop-1.7

I've added PrestaShop into my Windows 10 using Xampp. Now when I'm trying to install it by going to `://localhost/prestashop` it's giving the following diagnostic message:

> **Unable to generate private keys using openssl_pkey_new. Check your OpenSSL configuration, especially the path to openssl.cafile.**

Here's the Screenshot for it: [image: 1]

I've installed OpenSSL and made a few changes on my hosts file located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` but it still is not working and I'm clueless of how to set it up more properly.

Comment: In Windows you need to go in "Environment Variables" in "System Variables" Add Variable name: "OPENSSL_CONF" Variable Value: "E:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf"   path where you installed xampp. Restart PC It will work.

Comment: By naming "openssl.cafile" the PrestaShop installer is referring to [the PHP INI setting of the same name `openssl.cafile`, documented in the OpenSSL PHP Extension Runtime Configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php). Edit your PHP configuration, relying on the `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable might work as well, but better know where the configuration files are and how you edit them as the environment may change and editing it is not particularly comfortable. Additionally, only very little configuration settings have an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a diagnostic message that is common on Microsoft Windows running Xampp or Wampp.

For (Open)SSL to work there must be an environment variable named `OPENSSL_CONF` that points to the file named `openssl.cnf`.

Xampp and Wamp have that `openssl.cnf` file, but they don't create the correct paths to those files in the environment, namely the `OPENSSL_CONF` variable.

Previous and outdated versions of PrestaShop didn't bother either about SSL/TLS consequentially, but now for obvious reasons it is required to have it configured properly.

So it is not a problem with PrestaShop, but the system configuration.

This is how:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Windows Run prompt.

Type in `sysdm.cpl` and click OK. Open the Advanced tab and click on the Environment Variables button in the System Properties window.

Add (or edit) a variable named `OPENSSL_CONF`, with a value similar to `"C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf"` having the correct path to the file named `openssl.cnf` on your system where you installed Xampp. Note that after setting an environment variable you need to restart Windows for it to apply the changes (for the whole system including services like Xampp or Wamp.)

For more information about environment variables on your system, please consult the handbook (or manual) of your operating system. In case you don't have it at hand or you don't know where the information is located therein, contact vendor of your operating system for your support options.